# Cordova Angularjs geolocation and redirect not working

Tags: angularjs, cordova, geolocation

I am using cordova.geolocation and I am trying to redirect to next page if location service is on. But unfortunately it is not work. This is how my controller looks like

```
myApp.controller('checkLocation', ['$scope','$location','cordova','SessionService',function($scope,$location, cordova,SessionService) {
    function startRedirecting(){
        $location.path('/login');
    }
    function onSuccess(position) {
       /* alert('Latitude: '          + position.coords.latitude          + '\n' +
            'Longitude: '         + position.coords.longitude         + '\n' +
            'Altitude: '          + position.coords.altitude          + '\n' +
            'Accuracy: '          + position.coords.accuracy          + '\n' +
            'Altitude Accuracy: ' + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy  + '\n' +
            'Heading: '           + position.coords.heading           + '\n' +
            'Speed: '             + position.coords.speed             + '\n' +
            'Timestamp: '         + position.timestamp                + '\n');

        */
        SessionService.set('current_user_longitude',position.coords.longitude);
        alert(SessionService.get('current_user_longitude'));
        startRedirecting();
    };

// onError Callback receives a PositionError object
//
    function onError(error) {
        alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
            'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
    }


    cordova.ready.then(function(){

       // $location.path('/login');<--THIS WORKS
        if (!checkConnection()){
            navigator.app.exitApp();
        }
        else{
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
        }


        //checkConnection();
        /*var div = document.getElementById("map_canvas");
        map = plugin.google.maps.Map.getMap(div);
*/
    });
}]);
```

Any Suggestion